# How to save and use app's window size?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

Using .NET 4, what is the best way to save an app's window size and position at closing and use these values to start the app's window next time it is run?

I prefer not to have to touch any kind of registry but don't know if there is some kind of app.config (similar to web.config for ASP.NET apps) that I can use for Windows Presentation Foundation apps.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, all non-web .NET projects can make use of a configuration file, conventionally named `app.config`.

Comment: Why is this tagged winforms if you look for WPF solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Description

## Windows Forms

- Create Properties in Application Settings *LocationX*, *LocationY*, *WindowWidth*, *WindowHeight*  (of type *int*)
- Save Location and Size in `Form_FormClosed`
- Load and apply Location and Size in `Form_Load`

#### Sample

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Location = new Point(Properties.Settings.Default.LocationX, Properties.Settings.Default.LocationY);
    this.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.WindowWidth;
    this.Height = Properties.Settings.Default.WindowHeight;
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.LocationX = this.Location.X;
    Properties.Settings.Default.LocationY = this.Location.Y;
    Properties.Settings.Default.WindowWidth = this.Width;
    Properties.Settings.Default.WindowHeight = this.Height;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

#### More Information

- [Application Settings for Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx)
- [MSDN - Form.Load Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx)
- [MSDN - Form.Closed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx)

## WPF

- Create Properties in Application Settings *LocationX*, *LocationY*, *WindowWidth*, *WindowHeight* (of type *double*)
- Save Location and Size in `MainWindow_Closed`
- Load and apply Location and Size in `MainWindow_Loaded`

### Sample

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Left = Properties.Settings.Default.LocationX;
    this.Top = Properties.Settings.Default.LocationY;
    this.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.WindowWidth;
    this.Height = Properties.Settings.Default.WindowHeight;
}

void MainWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.LocationX = this.Left;
    Properties.Settings.Default.LocationY = this.Top;
    Properties.Settings.Default.WindowWidth = this.Width;
    Properties.Settings.Default.WindowHeight = this.Height;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

#### More Information

- [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx)
- [MSDN - FrameworkElement.Loaded Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [MSDN - Window.Closed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx)

## I have tested both, WinForms and WPF.

Comment: i recommend adding a check in the loaded handler to see if the width or height is 0 or less than some small number.

Comment: This way the full screen size is saved if you maximize the Application, so the regular window size isn't saved. Better check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30165932/9758687

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to save just *one* window `position` and `size`, I would suggest to save them in [applicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

If you more window settings to save, or more windows to manage I would, personally suggest to save it in separate `XML` file.

**EDIT**

[Working with XML standart way example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli2111282005041517AM/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli21.aspx)

[LINQ to XML example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was already answered a long time ago, but, this is the most elegant solution that I've found over the internet after searching two days for a decent solution. Check this out:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidrickard/archive/2010/03/09/saving-window-size-and-location-in-wpf-and-winforms.aspx

It works for WPF and for WinForms too.