# Dimension easy to setup screen WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to set the screen with the following dimensions Height = "768" Width = "1024", but would like the numeric values ​​stay in the app.config because some change I change in one corner and reflect on all the other occurs.

Any suggestions?

```
<Window x:Class="Smart.Interface.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Smart.Interface.View"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Smart.Interface.ViewModel"
        Title="Smart - Modular Technologies" Height="768" Width="1024"
        DataContext="{Binding Login,
                              Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Comment: You _can_ do it but _why_? What do you mean _some change I change in one corner and reflect on all the other occurs_?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save and use app's window size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751650/how-to-save-and-use-apps-window-size)

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. But I want to define a single value for height and width that I can use in all XAML. If for some reason this change values ​​I set in one corner, ie no need to change this value on each screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess would be to create a style for your windows:

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="MyWindowStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="1024" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="768" />
</Style>
```

Another suggestion would be to add the `Width` and `Height` as `StaticResource`s:

In App.xaml

```
<Application ...
         xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Application.Resources>
        <system:Double x:Key="ScreenWidth">1024</system:Double>
        <system:Double x:Key="ScreenHeight">1024</system:Double>
```

In Window code:

```
 <Window ... 
    Height="{StaticResource ScreenHeight}" 
    Width="{StaticResource ScreenWidth}">
```